# How can I convert this sentence from first person to third person

Tags: grammatical-person

I'm writing an academic paper and need some help writing this sentence in third person.

This is what I want to say in third person (currently in first person):

> The kitchen was assigned to a different engineer, while I was assigned the
>   living room.

I was thinking the third person would look like this? :

> The kitchen was assigned to a different engineer, while he was assigned the
>   living room.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The author needs to clarify what in the world he is talking about here.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's confusing you?

Comment: That was a sample solution. :)

Comment: Aw man, I wondered if that was what you were trying to say. So `The kitchen was assigned to a different engineer, while the author was assigned the living room.` would do?

Comment: Sure, that’s just fine, and reasonably customary.

Comment: The living room was assigned to the author, while the kitchen was assigned to a different engineer.

Comment: @tchrist - I've been thinking about raising something on Meta about cryptic comments such as your first (very clever by the way). Do you have any objection to my using yours as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to change Edwin's answer the tiniest bit, but he should get the credit for this answer.

> The author was assigned the living room, while another engineer was given the kitchen.

Comment: Might as well mark this correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  There are two different types of third-person writing though:

- Third Person Omniscient (all knowing)
- Third Person Limited
- Third Person Objective
- Third Person Subjective

(Source http://mywritingnotebook.com/2012/01/08/note-253-four-types-of-third-person-point-of-view-pov-in-writing/)

If you have a main character in your writing, you would use "he/she" to describe them but the story would be told from their point of view exclusively.  I think with an academic paper, however, you might write it in Third Person Omniscient?  If that were the case, you could express the emotions/thoughts of ALL the characters in your paper, not just one of them.

"The kitchen was assigned to a different engineer, while he was assigned the living room."  Your example is **written in Third Person Limited** because it seems to have a main character (the "I" that was changed to "he"; "he" is the main character).

You can also **refer to the main character in Third Person writing by their name**.  For example, you could have said "the kitchen was assigned to a different engineer, while Michael was assigned to the living room".  (Assuming the character's name is Michael.)

You would introduce him as Michael in the beginning and then alternate between using his name and referring to him as "he".  Sometimes if there are a lot of other male characters in a particular scene, you need to clarify who "he" is and in that situation you would use the character's name instead of calling him "he".