# I will discuss in third person?

Tags: british-english, third-person

What is the correct way of writing "I will discuss" in a third person form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"He/She will discuss"

Or

"Mary will discuss" (assuming you're Mary)

Depending on the context, you can pick either.
There's also a similar question/thread you can refer to:

[How can I convert this sentence from first person to third person](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266682/how-can-i-convert-this-sentence-from-first-person-to-third-person)

Hope that helps!